# How to align a new row to a table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ascx

I have a table but I added a new tr to the table, it is hidden and I show it using js, the point here is that it no longer aligns like the others  and I can not align it in javascript I only do the following, someone who Know how I can align it correctly?

```
function setText() {
  var adultText = Dom.get("adultRateText");
  var divTable = Dom.getElementsByClassName("idCustom");
  var divUnitTable = Dom.getElementsByClassName("idUnit");

  if (perVehicle.checked) {
      //adultText.innerHTML = "Net Rate";
      Dom.setStyle(onlyNetRates, "display", "inline-block");
      Dom.setStyle(netRatesDiv, "display", "inline-block");
      Dom.setStyle(adultsArea, "display", "none");

  }
  else {
      //adultText.innerHTML = "Adult Net Rate";

      Dom.setStyle(adultsArea, "display", "inline-block");
      Dom.setStyle(onlyNetRates, "display", "none");
      Dom.setStyle(netRatesDiv, "display", "none");
  }
  for (var z = 0; z < divTable.length; z++) {
     Dom.setStyle(divTable[z], "display", (!perVehicle.checked) ? "none" : "");
  }
  for (var z = 0; z < divUnitTable.length; z++) {
     Dom.setStyle(divUnitTable[z], "display", (perVehicle.checked) ? "none" : "");
  }  
 }
```

The image is this

[image]

Comment: what is 'Dom' ?

Comment: Try with `visibility: hidden` over the `display: none`.